# Pyspark: Generate a column based on another column that has repeatedly appended values upto the current row

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

This is my dataframe:

[image]

I would like to generate the column **B** for each product in the **Product** column.

I tried with Lead/Lag functions of pyspark but wasn't able to generate it exactly.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please include whatever code and errors you're encountering in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **`F.collect_list`** and **`explode`** functions.

`F.collect_list` over a window would cumulatively append the lists in column `A`. 
`explode` and `collect_list` can merge the list of lists into one.

Your df:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = StructType([StructField("product", StringType()), StructField("year", IntegerType()), \
    StructField("A", ArrayType(IntegerType()))])

data = [['A', 2010, [1,2,3]], ['A', 2011, [4,5,6]], ['A', 2012, [7,8,]], \
    ['B', 2009, [10,11,12]], ['B', 2010, [16,17]], ['B', 2011, [20,21,22,23]], ['B', 2012, [24]]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=schema)
```

```
w = Window.partitionBy("product").orderBy("year")

df.withColumn("first_list", F.collect_list("A").over(w))\
    .withColumn("first_explode", F.explode((F.col("first_list"))))\
    .withColumn("second_explode", F.explode(F.col("first_explode")))\
    .withColumn("cum_list", F.collect_list("second_explode").over(Window.partitionBy("product", "year")))\
    .drop("first_list", "first_explode", "second_explode").distinct()\
    .orderBy("product", "year").show(truncate=False)
```

(Use `F.collect_set` on `second_explode` if you don't want duplicates)

Output:

```
+-------+----+----------------+----------------------------------------+        
|product|year|A               |cum_list                                |
+-------+----+----------------+----------------------------------------+
|A      |2010|[1, 2, 3]       |[1, 2, 3]                               |
|A      |2011|[4, 5, 6]       |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]                      |
|A      |2012|[7, 8]          |[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]                |
|B      |2009|[10, 11, 12]    |[10, 11, 12]                            |
|B      |2010|[16, 17]        |[10, 11, 12, 16, 17]                    |
|B      |2011|[20, 21, 22, 23]|[10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23]    |
|B      |2012|[24]            |[10, 11, 12, 16, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]|
+-------+----+----------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Even simpler using array functions: `df.withColumn("B", collect_list("A").over(w)).withColumn("B", array_distinct(flatten("B")))`

Comment: Cool! I'm using Spark 2.3. I guess `array_distinct` is available only in Spark >= 2.4

Comment: Thanks a lot Surya Murali and @blackbishop for your solutions! :) Is there any efficient way to do this? This seems to take around 15 seconds just for this sample dataset. I am working on a much larger dataset for which I am afraid it might take hours. Any suggestions would be appreciated! :)